# How to Multiselect Angular

Tags: angular, dropdown

I have a problem. I have code and have result that what i want [img normal multiselect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7d6Uh.png) But when i change it with real data with angular, that result is not what i want [img angular multiselect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czHIG.png) Here is my code

```
<select class="js-select2" id="id" name="" style="width: 100%;" data-placeholder=".."multiple >
  <option></option>
  <option value="175">jerapah</option>
  <option value="174">kadal</option>
  <option value="171">buaya</option>
  <option value="170">tokek</option>
```

And this is my code with angular

```
<select class="js-select2" ng-model="filterParameter.rolling" id="id" name="" style="width: 100%;" data-placeholder=".."multiple >
 <option ng-repeat="m in filterList.rolling.items" value="{{m.value}}">{{m.text}}</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your event click/select you need to edit/add objet attributes 
lets say you have this object :

```
 { name : 'jam' , age : 16 }
```

on click/select : it will be

```
 { name : 'jam' , age : 16, setected : true }
```

then you can play with your logic.

i hope that help

Comment: i ever insert selected inside my select, but it does not work –